# Scala inheritance from Java class: select which super constructor to call

Tags: inheritance, scala

I have multiple constructor in a Java class.

```
public class A{
  public A(){...}
  public A(String param){...}
  public A(String param, Object value}
}
```

Now I want to create a Scala class that inherit from that class

```
class B extends A{
  super("abc")
}
```

But this syntax is invalid. Scala is complaining that `'.' expected but '(' found.`

What is the valid way to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to append the constructor arguments to the class definition like this:

```
class B extends A("abc")
```

Answer (score 31):

As Moritz says, you have to provide the constructor args directly in the class definition. Additionally you can use secondary constructors that way:

```
class B(a:String, b:String) extends A(a,b) {
  def this(a:String) = this(a, "some default")
  def this(num:Int) = this(num.toString)
}
```

But you *must* refer to `this`, `super` is not possible.